# Chart.js how to highlight a part of a label

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

i am trying to highlight part of a label from the axis labels based on what the user has searched for.

However the label is being rendered as text so the html tags are shown like plain text. any ideas on how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). It offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. In below code snippet, I use the `afterDraw` hook to [draw text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText) of different styles underneath each bar.

> When drawing your own tick labels, probably want to define the text rotation. Further you need to instruct Chart.js not to display the default labels. This can be done through the following definition inside the chart `options`.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      display: false,
      rotation: 40
    }
  }],
```

> You also need to define some `padding` for the bottom of the chart, otherwise you won't see your custom tick labels.

```
layout: {
  padding: {
    bottom: 60
  }
},
```

Please take a look at below code sample and see how it works. Tick labels that need to be drawn with two different styles are separated with a semicolon inside `data.labels`.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      let yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      chart.data.labels.forEach((l, i) => {
        let labelTokens = l.split(';');        
        let rotation = xAxis.options.ticks.rotation * -Math.PI / 180;
        let x = xAxis.getPixelForValue(l);        
        if (labelTokens.length == 2) {
          ctx.save();
          let width = ctx.measureText(labelTokens.join(' ')).width;
          ctx.translate(x, yAxis.bottom + 10);
          ctx.rotate(rotation);
          ctx.font = 'italic 12px Arial';
          ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
          ctx.fillText(labelTokens[0], -width, 0);
          ctx.restore();
        }
        ctx.save();
        let labelEnd = labelTokens[labelTokens.length - 1];
        let width = ctx.measureText(labelEnd).width;
        ctx.translate(x, yAxis.bottom + 10);
        ctx.rotate(rotation);
        ctx.font = '12px Arial';        
        ctx.fillText(labelEnd, -width, 0);
        ctx.restore();
      });
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['NASTY!!;Errors', 'Warnings'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Result',
      data: [30, 59],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)'],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        bottom: 60
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        title: tooltipItem => tooltipItem[0].xLabel.split(';').join(' ')
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false,
          rotation: 40
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="10" height="8"></canvas>
```